# How to format the first line of a post differently?

Tags: theme-development, single, css

I'd like to have the first paragraph/sentence of my posts in their single.php page styled differently - say... bold.

How do I go about doing that in the most efficient way?

Comment: Explain why `:first-line` is not an option.

Comment: two reasons: 1. didn't know it exist. 2. I need the first sentence. this only gets me a fragment of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, this is the function that worked for me:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'first_line_bold');
function first_line_bold($content)
{
    if (!is_page()) {
      $pattern = "/<p.*?>([^`]*?)<\/p>/";
      $match = "<span style=\"font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;\">$1</span>";
      $content = preg_replace($pattern, $match, $content, 1);
      return $content;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the idea

```
add_filter('the_content', 'testfunc');

function custom_formatter($matches){
  return "<strong>{$matches[0]}</strong>";
}

function testfunc($content)
{
  $pattern = "$\<p.*\>(.*)\<\/p\>$";
  $content = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'custom_formatter', $content);
  return $content;
}
```

However, you will need a better regular expression in `$pattern` variable as this regex may be very poor. in the `custom_formatter` function you can do the formattings you want.

Comment: The above doesn't work. The pattern doesn't really catch the first paragraph. I worked something else out and posted it as an answer here.